# Extract const char from std::string without copying?

Tags: c++, string, std

I was wondering if there is some way to tell the `std::string` to *release* the `char*` it is using.

I imagine that somewhere on the `std::string` it has a field of type `char*`, I was wanting some method that would to something like that:

```
const char* std::string::release() {
    const char* result = __str;
    __size = 0;
    __capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY_WHATEVER;
    __str = new char[INITIAL_CAPACITY_WHATEVER];
    return result;
}
```

Not that copying the content is a problem or will affect my performance, I just was felling uncomfortable with wasting time copying something that I am just going to delete after.

Comment: No, there is not, except to move it to another `std::string`. Why do you need this?  Why can't you just use `c_str()`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I dont need. I was just wondering.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Whenever I see stuff like this, my first thought is "C API/interop".  Maybe he needs to pass a `char**` to a function that may reallocate it?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well that certainly won't come to anything good, since `std::string` uses `std::allocator<char>`, and a C function would use free/malloc or realloc.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes. I'm just saying that's the #1 cause of questions like this in my memory, is C APIs.  Turns out this one is hypothetical, and not a C interop thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::move` to [move the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me) of one string object to another string object.  This avoids the overhead of copying.

```
std::string s1 = "hello";
std::string s2(std::move(s1));
```

However, you cannot directly disassociate the internal `char*` buffer from an instance of `std::string`. The `std::string` object *owns* the internal `char*` buffer, and will attempt to deallocate it when the destructor is invoked.